# Firebase query in swift not working properly as usual

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have firebase database structure like this
[image]

All I want is those data  which start with string '48DqysTKV0cMGf8orGlfhNaFLEw2' in the location "request/waiting"

My code is like below
[image]

But this code returns all the array in the waiting node not the specific nodes

Comment: Code posted as an image is frowned upon. Please post your code as part of the question.

Comment: If it helped, please, mark my post as answer (press jackdaw) to let others know, that it is correct

Comment: It's not working with me

Comment: I need all nodes starting with substring '48DqysTKV0cMGf8orGlfhNaFLEw2'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why is because you're using `.childAdded`. When called, initially it retrieves every element in the given path, thereafter it starts monitoring for added nodes only. More [info](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data).

Use `.value` instead in your query.

`queryStarting(atValue)` doesn't work the way you think it does. To achieve what you want, you need to limit your queries to a certain range/boundary. Read the different [query types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseQuery#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseQuery(im)queryStartingAtValue:childKey:) and decide for yourself which combination makes sense.

Comment: .value returns all the array in the "request/waiting" location not the matched data which i want

Answer (score 0):

Try this (I think the problem in `childAdded`. Change it to `.value`):

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database()
              .reference(withPath: "request/waiting")
              .queryStarting(atValue: "48DqysTKV0cMGf8orGlfhNaFLEw2")
              .queryEnding(atValue: "48DqysTKV0cMGf8orGlfhNaFLEw2" + "\u{f8ff}")

ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in 
    if let data = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] {
        // code..
    }
})
```

> The f8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a 48DqysTKV0cMGf8orGlfhNaFLEw2.

Hope it helps

Comment: I need waiting requests which start with this substring "48DqysTKV0cMGf8orGlfhNaFLEw2" understand ?

Comment: @user3755242 problem with type. Should use .value instead of .childAdded

Comment: Your code returns only one snapshot not all snapshots starting with "48DqysTKV0cMGf8orGlfhNaFLEw2-23432424"

Comment: @user3755242 only in request/waiting? You need starts with

Comment: @VladPulichev It'll be useful to explain _\u{f8ff}_

Comment: @eshirima Thanks for your note. It's sequence of any symbols

Comment: @eshirima The f8ff character used in the query above is a very high code point in the Unicode range. Because it is after most regular characters in Unicode, the query matches all values that start with a te48DqysTKV0cMGf8orGlfhNaFLEw2-23432424t. Edited answer

Comment: @user3755242 and where was error? It is interesting 4 me. Cz it should work

Comment: startAt method is not working with key names properly. so i changed the query

Comment: @user3755242 on what? Thanks